# When using nuxt and tailwind external css file does not work

Tags: css, nuxt.js, tailwind-css

I want to use an external .css file but It does not work. I have tried link rel="stylesheet" and @importing css in style tags but it does not work

Comment: for importing css file to your nuxt app open yout `nuxt.config.js` file and in css section add your css files like:
``` css: ['~layouts/global.css']```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for importing css file to your nuxt app open yout nuxt.config.js file and in css section add your css files like:  `css: ['~layouts/global.css']` – [Ali Hosseini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8763985/ali-hosseini)

Comment: Hi @garbg - if a question was answered, please just use the "Answered" flag next to the correct answer instead of posting another "answer" :)

Comment: There is no way to set a comment as an answer though

Comment: Ohh, sorry @Garbg - I didn't see that in the review queue. Instead, you could add the answer from the comment to your "own" answer, or (even better) tell (in this case) ali hosseini to move the comment :)